# Calling Java application (.jar) using JavaScript in a Firefox extension

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am writing a Java application as a Firefox extension.
I need the JavaScript to call my external java application and pass one parameter to it.

But... how to do this? Any idea?

Comment: How about using Applets? You can call an Applet's function from JavaScript and do whatever you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short and with out isFileExists or try catch:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
                            createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

                file.initWithPath(path);
var oProcess = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].
                                        createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);

                    oProcess.init(file);
var args = null;
 var argsLen = 0;
if (params) {
args = [params];
argsLen = 1;
 }


oProcess.run(false, args, argsLen);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: is Path the Jar file Path? (file.initWithPath(path))